# servlet unable to save to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I am writing a simple servlet program in which I am trying to save web form data(jsp) to mySQL database.  I am getting a http status 404. 
Here is my code

My FirstServlet.java file is

```
package first;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.*;
```

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public FirstServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
* @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response)
*/
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String title = "Employee Management form";
 String docType =
 "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
 "transitional//en\">\n";
 out.println(docType +
           "<html>\n" +
           "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
           "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0c0\">\n" +
           "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
           "<ul>\n" +
           "  <li><b>First Name</b>: "
           + request.getParameter("first_name") + "\n" +
           "  <li><b>Last Name</b>: "
           + request.getParameter("last_name") + "\n" +
           "</ul>\n" +
           "</body></html>");

 try {

 Connection myConn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world", "root" , "password");
 System.out.println("Loading driver...");
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println("Driver loaded!");

Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
//ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from countrylanguage");
String sql = "insert into countrylanguage"
+ " (CountryCode, Language, IsOfficial, Percentage)"
+ " VALUES ('dvi', 'engli', 'T', '9.3')";

myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);

}
catch (Exception exc) {
exc.printStackTrace();
 }
}
// Method to handle POST method request.
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
doGet(request, response);
 }
}
```

The index.jsp file is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Welcome to Employee Management Project</H1>
<form action="FirstServlet" method="GET">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"> <br /> 
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="add" /> Add <input type="checkbox"    name="search" /> Search <input
        type="checkbox" name="delete" /> Delete  <input type="checkbox"
        name="update" /> Update <br /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>HelloServlet2</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>first.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Following is the hierarchy of the folder

```
HelloSevrvlet2
 Java Resources
  src
   first
    FirstServlet.java
 Libraries
  Apache Tomcat v7.0
  EAR Libraries
  JRE System Library
  Web App Libraries
 WebContent
  WEB-INF
   Lib
   web.xml
 index.jsp
```

Comment: try `action="/FirstServlet"`

Comment: Tried it. Still getting the error.

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: Try `action="FirstServlet"`. From `/FirstServlet`, the browser will construct an absolute URL like `http://localhost/FirstServlet`, which might or might not work depending on the mapping of the root of your application. On the other hand, action set to `FirstServlet` will result in an URL relative to the location of `index.jsp` (e.g. `http://localhost/yourapproot/FirstServlet`, which is what you actually want.

Comment: `//@WebServlet("/FirstServlet") `
try to uncomment this line

Comment: removed but still getting the error

Comment: How to pass values from the web form to database. My code is giving error. In the above code I am using values but how to use variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the form statement in the jsp file.
You have:
        
The "HelloServlet2" has been mistakenly spelt as HelloSevrvlet2. Once you correct this problem, your code should work fine. I have personally tested your code with Glassfish server.

Comment: I fixed the typo. I do get the webpage to fill out the form but once I click submit my servlet does not display the name and gives Http Status 404 error.

Comment: My project folder HelloServlet2 has the red icon on it. But I don't see it in any of the subfolders or files. How can I find more information?

Comment: After submitting, when you get 4040 error, can you post the URL you see in your browser. I am able to run your code perfectly fine with the Employee Management Form showing the first name and the last name values as I entered. Although, this was using the glassfish server and not tomcat. But the server type should not matter.

Comment: I tried posting http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet2/FirstServlet?first_name=&last_name=     but still get the error.  
My project folder HelloServlet2 has the red compilation error icon on it. But I don't see it in any of the subfolders or files. How can I find more information?

Comment: Just a thought here. 'web.xml' file usually lives under WEB-INF folder. In the folder structure you have given, it is at the same level as WEB-INF. Try moving the web.xml to WEB_INF directory and try again. May be that's the reason tomcat is not able to find your applet.

Comment: did that, this time I get a different error message: HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class first

Comment: Well, at least we are one step further. If you are getting 500, there should be a stack trace in the server log of tomcat server. That should tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: This is what the console displays  now         SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FirstServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: first
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)

Comment: Based on various comments on your question, I gather that you have made a number of changes to the servlet as well as the deployment descriptor(web.xml). From the error stack you have just posted, tomcat is to instantiate a class called first for a servlet named FirstServlet. This can happen if the entry for the <servlet-class> is incorrect. Check the entry in web.xml. It should list the fully qualified class name, i.e., first.FirstServlet.

Comment: with that correction I am back to http status 404 error and console says SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FirstServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: first.FirstServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)

Comment: Can you post the latest version of FirstServlet.java and web.xml files. Maybe something may pop up if I had a look at the source code. Because I am able to run your application on my computer using NetBeans and Glassfish server.

Comment: When packaging a JavaEE web app in a .war file, the compiled java code resides under WEB-INF/classes folder. So in your case, the FirstServlet.class file should be located in WEB-INF/classes/first/FirstServlet.class. If you are using an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse, such a structuring of compiled code is taken care of by the IDE. If you do not have the classes in the structure I mentioned above, tomcat may complain about not being able to find the class.

Comment: In the .war file, there is also a META-INF directory at the same level as WEB-INF direcory. META-INF directory contains a MANIFEST.MF text file. The MANIFEST.MF file in my setup of your application contains the following 3 lines:                                                                                          Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_31-b13 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: Does it make a difference?

Comment: The entries in the Manifest file may not make a difference. But the compiled classes under WEB-INF/classes will.

Comment: I made a .war file by exporting my program. When I imported it and open it. I did not see WEB-INF/classes folder or FirstServlet.class file. And when I try to run it I get an error unable to start Tomcat server. In the console it says SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloServlet3]]

Comment: I think for now, use the earlier way of deploying your application, but just add the compiled java classes (along with package structure) under WEB-INF/classes. If that works, then you can experiment with creating and deploying a WAR file.

Comment: Since the error is ClassNotFoundException, it seems to be a configuration problem. I would very much like to see the latest version of 'web.xml' and 'FirstServlet.java'.

Comment: There is one problem I can see in the current version of code. The URL pattern for FirstServlet is configured as an annotation in the java class and also in web.xml. Since the url pattern in both cases is the same, there is a name clash. Comment out either the @WebServlet annotation in the java class file or comment out the servlet configuration information in web.xml. That should do the trick. Once this works, you will face a problem with the getting connection to the database. You need to load the driver class file before trying to get a connection.

Comment: I would recommend that you use annotations rather than deployment descriptor files. You will be able to catch errors during compile time rather than at runtime.

Comment: The directory structure of the application is as follows:

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to format the directory structure in comments.

Comment: The code works in Netbeans and GlassFish Server. I have some environmental issue with eclipse setup. Thank you Sandeep for your help!

Comment: How to pass values from the web form to database. My code is giving error. In the above code I am using values but how to use variable?

Comment: Load the driver before getting the connection, that will take care of the connection problem. Also you are not using the entries from the forms for the database. So the hardcoded values will be entered in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml, following line must be like this:

```
<servlet-class>first.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
```

and in jsp file your action must be :

```
action="/FirstServlet"
```

Comment: Changed the xml and jsp files but still getting the error. I also added the program folder hierarchy in the code.

Comment: Try changing action="/HelloSevrvlet2/FirstServlet"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get the values from JSP and store in a database table:
1. Create the table in the database

```
   create table emp(
      emp_id Integer primary key,
      first_name varchar(25),
      last_name varchar(25)
   )
```

The above mentioned 'create table' statment is for JavaDB database which comes bundled with Glassfish server. But you can tweak the create statement so that it can be run on the database of your choice.

2. The Java Servlet code ( I have just included the try/catch block for database
   interaction. Other parts of servlet code remain the same as you posted earlier.)

   ```
   // You do not need to load the driver class as JDBC now  
   // loads the required driver class automatically based on the   
   // connect string you specify in the getConnection() method.  
   Connection myConn = null;  
   try {  
       int emp_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emp_id"));  
       String first_name = (String) request.getParameter("first_name");  
       String last_name = (String) request.getParameter("last_name");  
       myConn = DriverManager.getConnection
       ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples", "app", "app");  
       String sql = "INSERT INTO emp"  
                  + " (emp_id, first_name, last_name)"  
                  + " VALUES (?,?,?)";  
       PreparedStatement myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);  
       myStmt.setInt(1, emp_id);  
       myStmt.setString(2, first_name);  
       myStmt.setString(3, last_name);  
       int status = myStmt.executeUpdate();  
       out.println(status + " rows inserted");  
       myConn.commit();  
       myConn.close();  
   } catch (Exception exc) {  
       exc.printStackTrace();  
       out.println(exc.getMessage());  
   }
   ```
3. Once you learn about technologies like Hibernate/JPA/JTA/JPQL, you will find that these APIs provide very powerful functionality for interacting with databases. Using these technologies, you will not have to interact with JDBC directly. For now, the solution I have given above should suffice.

Comment: How to add, delete, update and search the form values in the database?

Comment: You can add radio buttons to your jsp page, one for each database action. In the servlet, you can use getParameters() to fetch the selected radio button and accordingly use insert/update/delete/select statements to make changes to the database.